# Is there a quick way to recode several variables in the same manner mantaining both the original variables and the recoded ones?

Tags: r

So I have a dataset df that has a typical battery of questions with answer ranging from 1 to 5. What I need is to have these 6 variables recoded as (1&2 = 1) (3 = 2) (4&5 = 3) and at the same time keep the originals within the same dataframe. Is there a quick way to do this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

#Example dataframe

df <- data.frame(
  P7A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  P7B = c(2, 4, 1, 3, 5),
  P7C = c(1, 5, 3, 3, 2),
  P7D = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 4),
  P7E = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 2),
  P7F = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1))

#Select the 6 variables that need recoding. 

vP7 <- c("P7A", "P7B", "P7C", "P7D", "P7E", "P7F")

#Recode them into a new dataframe

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vP7, recode, '1' = 1, '2' = 1, '3' = 2, '4' = 3, '5' = 3)
```

So I tried this but in the resulting dataframe the initial variables are lost and I cant find a way to make every recoded variable a new variable with the same name of the original plus an r, like (P7A -> P7Ar).

Comment: You can add ".names" argument to `across` to indicate new column names, try something like `df %>%
  mutate(across(vP7, ~ recode(.x, "1" = 1, "2" = 1, "3" = 2, "4" = 3, "5" = 3), .names = "{col}_r"))`?

Comment: And note that `mutate_at` has been superseded by `mutate` `across`...

Comment: If you want `p7Ar` instead of `p7A_r` remove the underscore

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to recode the variables and keep the original variables while adding the recoded versions with "r" suffix to their names:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Select the variables that need recoding 
vP7 <- c("P7A", "P7B", "P7C", "P7D", "P7E", "P7F")

# Recode and create new variables with "r" suffix
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(vP7), list(original = ~ .,
                                    recoded = ~ case_when(. %in% c(1, 2) ~ 1,
                                                          . == 3 ~ 2,
                                                          . %in% c(4, 5) ~ 3),
                                    .names = "{col}r")))

# Now df2 contains both the original and recoded variables
```

In this code, `mutate(across(...))` is used to apply the specified transformations to the selected variables. The `.names` argument allows you to control the naming of the newly created variables. It combines the original variable name with "r" to create the recoded variable names.